# Is there a way to add Common Fields to multiple Feature Class's in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox, arccatalog

I've got a File Geodatabase that has many different feature class's.  Now versus adding common fields one feature class at a time to the attribute table is there a toolbox or way to add a field to multiple feature classes at once?

Comment: Outside of scripting it or building a model, I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with running Add Field GP tool in [batch mode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000000w000000). You will be able to browse to select multiple feature classes within a geodatabase.

[image]